# Distortions on Navigation Menu in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

We're seeing a phenomenon on the home page (and only the home page) of one of our sites.  When we open the page in `Experience Editor` `(Sitecore 9.2)` and click on the angle brackets `('>')` in the `navigation bar`, the icons in the dropdown menu that appears are stretched horizontally, distorting the resulting menu:

[image]

Is this a known thing, hopefully with a fix?

Comment: I would guess that the CSS on your site is conflicting and causing that problem.

Comment: That seems very likely.  I'm waiting for some feedback from the folks managing that CSS to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing with the distorted menu icons in Sitecore Experience Editor could be caused by a number of factors. However, there are a few things you could try to troubleshoot and possibly fix the issue:

1. Clear your browser cache: Sometimes, outdated cache files in your
   browser can cause display issues. Try clearing your browser cache and refreshing the page to see if the issue persists.
2. Check the CSS file(s): The issue could be related to a CSS rule that is affecting the menu icons on the home page. Check the CSS files related to the home page to see if there are any rules that could be causing the issue.
3. Check for JavaScript errors: If there are JavaScript errors on the home page, this could be causing the issue. Check your browser console for any JavaScript errors and address them accordingly.
4. Try disabling any custom scripts or stylesheets: If you have any custom scripts or stylesheets on the home page, try disabling them to see if the issue goes away.
5. Contact Sitecore support: If none of the above steps work, it may be worth contacting Sitecore support for further assistance.

I hope this helps!